# barcode with the value of barcode

Tags: barcode, tcpdf

```
$barcodeobj = new TCPDFBarcode($filesysid, 'C128');
$barcode = $barcodeobj->getBarcodeHTML(1, 20, 'black');
echo $barcode;
```

I am using the above code to generate a bar code of a specific value now it is generating ok. But I cant put the value of the bar code under the barcode

```html
<div style="font-size:0;position:relative;width:35px;height:20px;">
  <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:20px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-color:black;width:1px;height:20px;position:absolute;left:3px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-color:black;width:1px;height:20px;position:absolute;left:6px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:20px;position:absolute;left:11px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:20px;position:absolute;left:15px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:20px;position:absolute;left:18px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:20px;position:absolute;left:22px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-color:black;width:3px;height:20px;position:absolute;left:27px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-color:black;width:1px;height:20px;position:absolute;left:31px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:20px;position:absolute;left:33px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-color:black;width:0px;height:20px;position:absolute;left:35px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-color:black;width:0px;height:20px;position:absolute;left:35px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Now What I want is under the code I also get the textual representation.

Update:

> Example if I barcoded the numbers 1234 then under the barcode of 1234 I want to see 1234

Reason:

> My reason is so that if the barcode is crample or the scan is failing the user can just type in the code and search.

Comment: This barcode has no data in it. It is a start character, a checksum (for an empty string), and a stop character. What characters would you like to see under it?

Comment: @BrianAnderson i just copied the barcode representation from the development tools. What I want to see under the barcode is the data that was barcoded. Example if I barcoded the numbers 1234 then under the barcode of 1234 I want to see 1234

Comment: It looks like a very similar issue to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014875/display-number-below-1d-barcode-in-tcpdf?rq=1. Only the poster of that question specified they did not want to use HTML and draw the text underneath. They wanted the number placed in a PNG file with the barcode. Is there a reason you can't just add the text below the barcode in the same <div> and center it with inline style?

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that when you try to print a page with this barcode in it, it won't print. Is printing before it is turned into a PDF important?

Comment: yes I will print the PDF file of a document together with the barcode and its textual representation. I will check the link give me a moment

Comment: @BrianAnderson I think I want the same thing with the OP on the link but there was no answer on the OP. I was not able to see that OP during my search though. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation at https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_027/? They are using a different method to generate the barcode with text ($pdf->write1DBarcode('CODE 128 B', 'C128B', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');). They use a style array to set the text parameters.

Comment: I will check it @brian in a moment thank you for suggestions